# Binary classification not training correctly

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, training-data

I've been working on a neural network that can classify two sets of astronomical data. I believe that my neural network is struggling because the two sets of data are quite similar, but even with significant changes to the data, it still seems like the accuracy history doesn't behave how I think it would.

These are example images from each dataset:

[image: first dataset]
[image: second dataset]

I'm currently using 10,000 images of each type, with 20% going to validation data, so 16,000 training images and 4,000 validation images. Due to memory constraints, I can't increase the datasets much more than this.

This is my current model:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="valid", activation='relu', input_shape=(192, 192, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (9, 9), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))
```

which I'm compiling with:

```
opt = SGD(lr=0.1)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and fitting using:

```
history = model.fit(train, train_labels, batch_size=200, epochs=15, validation_data=(validation, validation_labels))
```

If I add something to the data to make the datasets unrealistically different (e.g. adding a random rectangle to the middle of the data or by adding a mask to one but not the other), I get an accuracy history that looks like this:

[image: accuracy history for artificially tuned datasets]

*(Note that the accuracy history for the training data was shifted half an epoch to the left to account for the training accuracy being measured, on average, half an epoch before the validation accuracy.)*

If I make the datasets very similar (e.g. adding nothing to the datasets or applying the same mask to both), I get an accuracy history that looks like this:

[image: accuracy history for similar datasets]

or occasionally with a big spike in validation accuracy for one epoch, like so:

[image: accurate, but only once]

Looking at different websites and other StackOverflow pages, I've tried:

- changing the number and size of the filters
- adding or subtracting convolutional layers
- changing the optimizer function (it was originally "adam", so it had an adaptive learning rate and I switched it to the above so I could manually tune the learning rate)
- increasing the batch size
- increasing the dataset (originally had only 5,000 images of each instead of 10,000),
- increasing the number of epochs (from 10 to 15)
- adding or subtracting padding from the convolutional layer
- changing the activation function in the last layer

Am I missing something? Are these dataset just too similar to achieve a binary classifcation network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a binary classification then you need to change:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid"))
```

into:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

Sigmoid indicates that if the output is bigger than some threshold(most of the times 0.5) then it belongs to second class etc. Also you really don't need to use `from_logits = True` since you specified an activation in the last dense layer.

Recall that your loss also should be:

```
tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits = False)
```

If you want to set `from_logits = True`, then your last dense layer should look like this:

```
model.add(layers.Dense(1)) # no activation, linear.
```

---

You can also use 2 neurons in the last dense layer but then you need to use `softmax` activation with categorical loss.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've switched the layer at the end to having `layers.Dense(1)`. I tried running it with `from_logits=False` and a sigmoid activation function and again with `from_logits=True` and no activation function, but both returned similar validation accuracies to the above, with the validation accuracy staying at 50% through all epochs and the training accuracy jumping between 100% and 50%

Comment: 0.1 LR is way too high, I'd try lowering it first. And then increase the size and number of filters in the CNN as your images get their dimensions reduced. Like `Conv2D(32,(3,3)) .. Conv2D(64,(3,3)` etc.

Comment: Thank you!! This looks much better. One last question so I understand what's happening: the validation accuracy still jumps between 50% and 100% accuracy before settling on 100% accuracy. I put it [here](https://imgur.com/DwCuRA8)  Is that normal? I would've expected a slowly increasing accuracy, not a jagged up and down increase like we see here

Comment: Maybe try adam optimizer with a lower learning rate, I assume there will be less oscillations. I don't think that's normal and can be related to your data actually. With my suggestions there should be no problems with the model after all. If the answer was helpful I'd be happy if you can accept it.